SQLAlchemy Psycopg3 hangs on engine.begin()
I initialized a SQLAlchemy/psycopg(3) connection/engine like:
engine = create_engine(
    PG_URI,
    echo=True,
    echo_pool=True,
    pool_size=3,
    pool_timeout=5,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    connect_args={
        "connect_timeout": 5,
        "options": f"-c statement-timeout={5 * 1000}",
    },
)

I realise when I use it later, it seems to hang at engine.begin() even tho I have configured connect_timeout (and hopefully set statement_timeout correctly, for example:
logger.info("Pinging Postgres (sync) ...")
with engine.begin() as conn: # Seems to hang here
    conn.execute(text("SELECT 1"))
    logger.info("Ping PG successful")
    return True

I noticed if I use NullPool its ok, so it seems like its failing to connect to the pool. Or perhaps reconnect, no logs related to pool tho, it seems to only print
Pinging Postgres (sync) ...

I think I need to pass reconnect_timeout for pool, but how?

reconnect_timeout (float, default: 5 minutes) – Maximum time, in seconds, the pool will try to create a connection. If a connection attempt fails, the pool will try to reconnect a few times, using an exponential backoff and some random factor to avoid mass attempts. If repeated attempts fail, after reconnect_timeout second the connection attempt is aborted and the reconnect_failed() callback invoked.

UPDATE:
Thanks to @IanWilson in the comments, seems like I should use echo_pool="debug" instead. Also I corrected statement_timeout (with underscore referencing PG Docs. However, this did not solve the problem. However, I did learn that its hanging at
sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Pool pre-ping on connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE]

I tried setting connect_args:
{
    "connect_timeout": 5,
    "options": "-c statement_timeout=5000 -c idle_session_timeout=5000 -c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=5000"
}

However, this only solves the problem partially in the case where the connection is idle for 5s, during the next pre-ping it will detect the connection is closed and reconnect. However, suppose it already obtained the connection, stop DB, now trigger a query, it will just hang at pre-ping again. Which timeout or option am I missing?
UPDATE 2:
Tried using psycopg(3) ConnectionPool manually
psycopg_pool = ConnectionPool(
    "postgresql://...",
    timeout=5,
    reconnect_timeout=5,
    reconnect_failed=lambda **kwargs: logger.error(
        "PG pool reconnect failed", **kwargs
    ),
    min_size=0,
    max_size=3,
)
sqlalchemy_pool = QueuePool(
    creator=psycopg_pool.getconn,
    pool_size=3,
    timeout=5,
)
connection_opts = {
    "statement_timeout": 5 * 1000,
    # "idle_session_timeout": 5 * 1000,
    # "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout": 5 * 1000,
    # "client_connection_check_interval": settings.PG_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
    # * 1000,
    # "tcp_keepalives_idle": 5,
    # "tcp_keepalives_interval": 5,
    # "tcp_keepalives_count": 1,
    # "tcp_user_timeout": 5 * 1000,
}
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg://...",,
    echo="debug",
    pool=self.sqlalchemy_pool,
    connect_args={
        "connect_timeout": 5,
        # See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS for options
        "options": " ".join([f"-c {k}={v}" for k, v in connection_opts.items()]),
    },
)

The only workaround I found so far appears to be using NullPool

I can't believe there are no logs.  When you use the null pool are there still no logs?  Are you sure you aren't reconfiguring logging later somehow?  Usually SA is pretty noisy.

Try echo_pool="debug" instead of echo_pool=True. sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo_pool

Also I guess why is it taking over 5 minutes to connect at all?

Also I think it is statement_timeout with an _.

@IanWilson you are correct, seems like echo_pool="debug" allows me to see logs. Now I can see that its stuck on sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Pool pre-ping on connection. But why does it not timeout?

I'm not sure but can you include the log in the question?  Are you actually able to connect to the server in other ways?  Also is this the very first connection from this pool or after it runs other things?

@IanWilson updated the OP with some updates. Seems like thats all the logs available. In this case, I am simulating the case where DB is down. So I manually downed the DB. The issue now seems like with those settings I can detect DB down if the connection isnt there yet. However, if the connection is alr open, DB goes down and I trigger a query, it attempts to connect forever

Looking at your link again, I'm not sure the sqlalchemy pool is using that psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool implementation at all unless you override the pool somehow.  Furthermore how long are you waiting for the connection to timeout?  Ie. Are you not waiting long enough?  It seems that the pre ping algorithm is a little unclear on how long it will take.  create-a-sqlalchemy-engine-using-an-existing-psycopg2-connection-pool

@IanWilson, actually I am also wondering what pool is SQLAlchemy using, I am not overriding the pool class or anything, currently only passing those options to create_engine. I am using psycopg3 so maybe abit different. Maybe let me explore what if I manually create a psycopg_pool.ConnectionPool

How are you simulating the disconnect?  Seems to work fine for me with default pool but I'm only using the same connection.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
